# javascript function convert into jquery equivalent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a javascript function written as follows which works just fine in **Firefox** for downloading given txt content.

```
  self.downloadURL = function (url) {
        var iframe;
        iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");        
        if (iframe === null) {
            iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
            iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
            iframe.style.display = "none";
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
        }
        iframe.src = url;
    }
```

but it does n't work fine with **IE 9** due to some reasons. So i tried to convert into equivalent jquery because jquery has compatibility with all the browsers.

here is the jquery equivalent of the same function:

```
   self.downloadURL = function (url) {
        var iframe;
        iframe = $("#hiddenDownloader");        
        if (iframe === null) {
            iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
            iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";            
            $("#hiddenDownloader").css("display", "none");
            $(document.body).append(iframe);
        }
        iframe.src = url;
    }
```

But now it does n't work in **both** the browsers. Please help letting me know what am i doing wrong.

Comment: Do you get any particular error message?

Comment: I dont get any particular error. it just does not respond in IE 9

Answer (score 9):

Your problem is in:

```
iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";
```

`iframe` refers to a jQuery Object not a DOM Node. You will have to use `.prop` to set the id:

```
iframe = $('<iframe></iframe>');
iframe.prop('id', "hiddenDownloader");
```

And also you have the same problem here:

```
if (iframe === null) {
```

Where you will need the check the length of `iframe`:

```
if (iframe.length === 0) {
```

And again at `iframe.src = url;` Maybe you can figure this one out:

```
iframe.attr('src', url);
```

**But why would you convert vanilla JavaScript to jQuery?**

Comment: `iframe.length === 0` (or maybe just `!iframe.length)` would be better than testing against `null` IMHO.

Comment: `iframe.length === 0` Sure think :)

Comment: @NULL No need for === 0.  `if (iframe.length)` will do just fine :)

Comment: @Archer I know. Its because 0 is falsy as a lot of other things is in JavaScript (undefined, null, "", etc). But `=== 0` is more clear for not so skilled programmer :)

Comment: Good point, and I've just realised that it had already been said and I also missed a `!`.  #Hangsheadinshame

Comment: @AlagesanPalani What doesnt work in IE. Do you get any script error ? Or maybe IE doesnt think that the file should be send to the download manager. This is a thing you normally control in the files headers on the server-side.

Comment: @NULL i did not get any error, it just keeps quiet. But it works fine in Firefox and opens up a dialog box to "save" or "Open" the text file content. so what is the solution to make it work in IE just like Firefox.?

Comment: @AlagesanPalani Almost explained it in my prev comment

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a strange way to download a file.

In any case, this probably works the same was as the original:

```
if (!iframe.get(0)) {
  ...
}
```

... and the `id` property as another poster mentions.

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
iframe = $("#hiddenDownloader")[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

- Replace `iframe.src = url;` with `iframe.attr("src",url + "?"+ Math.random());` ***to prevent caching issue in IE9***.
- Replace `iframe.id = "hiddenDownloader";` with `iframe.attr("id","hiddenDownloader");`
- Replace `if (iframe === null) {` with `if (iframe.length === 0) {`

Comment: @Alagesan Palani: this could be the caching problem in IE9, try my updated answer `url + "?"+ Math.random()`

Answer (score 0):

```
iframe = document.getElementById("hiddenDownloader");          
iframe = $("#hiddenDownloader");
```

These lines aren't equivalent. The second one create a jQuery object, so the check for null will never equate to true

Answer (score 0):

This link may help u:

http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?743000-IE9-Iframes-DOCTYPES-and-You

or u can add this to the top:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
```